# Flutter: How to load a huge image from network in Flutter?

Tags: image, dart, flutter

I try to load [this](http://img.mangachan.me/manga/-9new/b/1511440860_blessed_v1_ch1/__________________._.jpg) image using `NetworkImage` and show it. But instead i get half the picture and the rest is a white background on view and has very low quality. Please, help me how show this image or split this image on 3 image. Thanks.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKFmK.png)

[preview this picture on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw3Di.png)

Comment: Please display the relevant code in the text of the question rather than linking to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to set fit property as `BoxFit.fitWidth` and set the `width` size as the size of your screen.
Also you need to wrap the Image widget inside a `SingleChildScrollView` because your image is too large.

```
        return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  child: Image.network(
                    "http://img.mangachan.me/manga/-9new/b/1511440860_blessed_v1_ch1/__________________._.jpg",
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  ),
                ),
            );
```

Consider to split your large image into small pieces.

Comment: I thought about split image, but i'd don't know how to do it.(((

Comment: use different image for each slide :)

Comment: But i can't becouse i'm using html parser to create a manga reading app and i have only this picture)

Comment: That's another question, i solved your question, you can mark it as solved :) thanks